# In Java, can I use a primitive type literal or type variable in an instanceof expression?

Tags: java, instanceof

Can I use a primitive type literal or type variable in an `instanceof` expression?

```
class MyClass<T> {
    {
         boolean b1 = null instanceof T; // T erasure -> Object should be used
         boolean b2 = 2 instanceof Integer; // Incompatible operands
    }
```

I'm getting compilation errors. Is there any way to circumvent these errors and use a primitive type literal/type variable in an `instanceof` expression?

Basically, I want to be reassured that no, I will never be able to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, because of *type erasure*. An instance of `MyClass<T>` doesn't actually know what `T` is.

You need to have an instance of `Class<T>`. Then you can use the [`isInstance`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)) method. One way of doing that is to specify it in the constructor:

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    private Class<T> clazz;

    MyClass(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    // Now you can use clazz to check for instances, create new instances ect.
}
```

For the second one, the problem is the first operand, not the second. The primitive value itself isn't an instance of `Integer`; the boxed version is:

```
Object obj = 2;
boolean b2 = obj instanceof Integer;
```

Whenever you've got a genuine primitive value, you'll already know the type so making a dynamic type check doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

1. Due to type erasure, you cannot know what `T` is.
2. Literals (except for string literals) aren't objects.
   Therefore, no.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, instanceof askes for an object as left operand. Primitive variables are not objects, so no, you can't use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't do it.
2. Even if you could, you can't use it.

A typical usage of `instanceof` looks like

```
void somemethod(Collection c) {
    if (c instanceof List) {...}
}

somemethod(new ArrayList());
```

The important thing here is that you get an object of a supertype (here: Collection) which may or may not be instance of a subtype (here: List). With primitives this is impossible:

```
void anothermethod(double x) {
    .... // <------ X
}

anothermethod(42);
```

At the point X there's a variable x of type double, there's no hidden information about some int 42. The actual parameter 42 didn't masquerade as double, it's got **converted** to a double. That's why instanceof makes no sense for primitives.